# Dropdown Menu opens on the top on click after Jquery 1.12.4 update

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I have a group of buttons that opens up a menu on click. Recently we updated from Jquery 1.11 to Jquery1.12.4. After this update whenever the menu is clicked the menu opens on the top irrespective of the button and button width is decreased. When inspected even the body height shows only 658px fixed without any reason. I didn't give any fixed height anywhere in the app. When I tried the body height 500vh this works fine.

I tried to increase the body height with min-height:100vh, still doesn't work, It stays 658px;

```
<div class="dropdown col-lg-12 claim-card-container">
<div class="claim-card-button-div" ng-repeat="record in wData.records">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle claim-card" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
<div class="claim-card-header">
<p class="date">  record.Status  </p>
</div>
<div class="claim-card-body">
<div class="claim-card-body-information">
<p class="name">record.Name</p>
<div class="underline"></div>
</div>
</div>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li ng-repeat="menuItem in record.ContextMenu.MenuItems">
<a tabindex="0" role="link" ng-click="contextMenuClicked(menuItemId: menuItem.Id, record: record)">menuItem.Text</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

It is also giving an error in the console.

> index.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of null
>
> ```
> at new t (index.js:38)
> at c.t.toggle (dropdown.js:176)
> at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (dropdown.js:374)
> at Function.each (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
> at n.fn.init.each (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
> at n.fn.init.c._jQueryInterface [as dropdown] (dropdown.js:361)
> at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (dropdown.js:518)
> at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3)
> at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3)
> ```

Comment: instead of `jquery` try `jQuery` - it will probably solve your height issue.

Comment: It's giving the error in index.js file. I don't know where to change the jquery to jQuery.  These are all library files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this is the answer but it worked for me. You can check your Pooper.Js version. I updated my Popper.js to 1.14.6 and it is fixed now. Hope this might help.